# Better way to update with a specific query

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Here is the case: I want to update a document with a specific id and its update_time is older than the newer one, if such a document is not found, create a doc with the newer one.

The first solution to me is:

```
db.collection.update(
  {
    '_id': 'the_specific_id',
    'update_time': {'$lt': new_date_time}
  },
  {
     '$set' :{
        'field_1': 'value_1',
        'field_2': 'value_2',
        'update_time': new_data_time
     }

  },
  {  'upsert': true}
)
```

In this solution, if doc is found, then update is fine. If doc is not found due to '_id' not found, upsert is fine. However If doc is not found because the doc in db has a newer 'update_time', a following upsert is not right (because of primary key duplication).

So I have to end up with this (psudo code):

```
try:
   db.collection.insert({
    '_id': 'the_specific_id',
    'field1': 'value1',
    'field2': 'value2',
    'update_time': new_date_time
  })
except Exception as e:
   if e.message.find('duplication'):
       db.collection.update(
        {
         '_id': 'the_specific_id',
         'update_time': {'$lt': new_date_time}
        },
        {
          '$set' : {
             'field_1': 'value_1',
             'field_2': 'value_2',
             'update_time': new_data_time
           }
        },
        {  'upsert': false})
```

This looks over complicated. I wonder if any better way on this solution?

Comment: There are ways, but if you are "really" using the `_id` field then it's already "unique", so an "upsert" **cannot** occur and you would instead receive a duplicate key error and nothing would be altered. Other solutions vary on the same principle, but `_id` basically covers it and the "upsert" is perfectly fine in this instance, as presented. The absence of `$set` or other update operators in your question is more troublesome really, since you would in fact "overwrite" other fields such as `"update_time"` data without them. Hence every second write would try to upsert and fail on the dup key.

Comment: '$set' operator added

Comment: I think the more important **fact** there is **it is not possible to duplicate a primary key**. No upsert can occur due to a date mismatch. It's result will always be a duplicate key error. Which is the essence of how you achieve what you want. So if you are telling the truth here, then the "upsert" already works.

Comment: Why are you adding silly sentences to your post? The **FIRST** approach already works as designed. You cannot create a new document with the same `_id` and a newer date. because you simply **cannot create another document with the same _id**. How that is not sinking in yet beats me.

Comment: so still needs  try except block, any cleaner way?

Comment: Please actually read the documentation: ["The _id Field"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-id-field). Use the "upsert" **only** statement and expect it to throw an exception. So handle that. **YES** It is the cleanest way. One statement with an exception check is as clean as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the search first, to only look for items which have an update less than the new update time. Once these selections are satisfied, then you can use the upsert as before.

```
  db.collection.update(
  {
    '_id': 'the_specific_id',
    'update_time': {'$lt': new_date_time}
  },
  {
    'field_1': 'value_1',
    'field_2': 'value_2',
    'update_time': new_date_time
  },
  {  'upsert': true}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**findOrCreate**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/findorcreate-promise) which is used for promises but this includes `{upsert:true}` statement also which can help you in update , create mechanism.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Neil Lunn, the simplest way of doing this is:

```
try: 
  db.collection.update(
  {
    '_id': 'the_specific_id',
    'update_time': {'$lt': new_date_time}
  },
  {
   '$set' :{
    'field_1': 'value_1',
    'field_2': 'value_2',
    'update_time': new_data_time }
  },
  {'upsert': true})
except DuplicateKeyError as e:
  pass
```